# Erro no Vscode ao executar um código na linguagem Python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, terminal

Quando eu digito uma função simples na linguagem Python e tento executar no terminal do VScode, dá esse erro:

> soma : O termo 'soma' não é reconhecido como nome de cmdlet, função,
> arquivo de script ou programa operável. Verifique a grafia do nome ou,
> se  um caminho tiver sido incluído, veja se o caminho está correto e
> tente novamente. No linha:1 caractere:1
> soma(4,3)
> CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (soma:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
> FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Answer (score -1):

Você tem que execultar seu arquivo python no terminal e não o nome do método que está no arquivo.

Ex:

> python meuarquivo.py

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Olá, Marco. Muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score -3):

Tenta fazer dessa forma:

soma = (4,3)

print(soma)

O print vai aparecer dessa forma:
(4,3)

Se você deseja fazer a soma coloque dessa forma:

soma = 4 + 3

print(soma)